# Minimal way to add text to scrbook header/footer

Tags: header-footer, scrbook

I am using scrbook class and have not configured it much. I don't intend to.

By default, the header for non-chapter pages is the section title, left-aligned on even pages and right-aligned on odd pages. Similarly, the footer is just the page number.

I simply want to add text to the footer (let's say it should now read `Draft v1.1 Page #pagenumber`). When I search for advice on how to modify the header/footer, I get examples which are doing more complicated things than just this.

I don't need the complexity of what other people are doing. I just want to replace the footer text with the above schema.

**What's the minimal-code way to do this?** I don't particularly care if I lose odd/even alignment or other such cosmetic tweaks, I just want to keep it simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redefine `\pagemark` to add the additional information:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand\pagemark{{%
  \usekomafont{pagenumber}Draft v1.1 Page \thepage
}}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for the dummy text in this example
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you do not want to use the font element `pagenumber`:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\renewcommand\pagemark{Draft v1.1 Page \thepage}

\usepackage{blindtext}% only for the dummy text in this example
\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\renewcommand\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings} % ensures that the first page of chapters is formatted the same
\ofoot{Draft v1.1 Page \pagemark}
\begin{document}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\lipsum\lipsum
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]